# Vue template import

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to show a modal in my application. I'm using [Buefy, heres the link to the pen](https://codepen.io/pshu1/pen/poyBzqr?editable=true&editors=101%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fbuefy.org%2Fdocumentation%2Fmodal%2F). I have moved all my code for the template section to `Modal.vue`. I also want to define methods there to handle the button clicks. How would I load it then? I want to be able to read the data entered in the modal and do something with it.

For now, I had changed my template line to `template : require('./Modal.vue')` but my console says

```
[Vue warn]: invalid template option:[object Module]
```

Am I having a syntax error or the way I'm going about it is incorrect?